# how to check if a block is there and if so emit a redstone signal in Minecraft 1.12.2 vanilla

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

im trying to make it so a command block emits a redstone signal if a block is there. im trying to do this in Minecraft 1.12.2.

Comment: What have you already tried, and did you do any research before asking? Arqade works best when you share past research/past trials, that way we can see the specific problem you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about the "testforblock" command:
https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/testforblock_command.php

You can have the command block say `/testforblock <x> <y> <z> <block>`

Heres an example: `/testforblock ~ ~-1 ~ diamond_ore`

The /testforblock command works in 1.12.2

To have it continuously check, set it to repeat.

To detect when it has found the block, you can have a comparator running out from the command block.

Comment: Ok sorry I'll do that next time.

Comment: The question explicitly states that the OP is using Minecraft 1.12.2

Comment: @RayWu `/testforblock` works in 1.12. What makes you think that darthvader1925 didn't take the version number into account?

Comment: I have edited it. I hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 Sorry, I confused 1.12 and 1.13.